# Make isort recognize imports from Django apps as first-party imports

Tags: python, django, isort

I'm working on a project with many different Django apps.

I want to use `isort` on this project but the imports from Django apps (`from myapp1.mymodule import myfunction`) are seen by `isort` as third-party imports.

How can I make `isort` recognize them as first-party imports?

I could add in the `isort` configuration (in the `.cfg`): `known_first_party=myapp1,myapp2...` but I'll have to maintain this list.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `src_paths` option to specify the project folder. You are do not need to maintain `known_first_party` list. Related source code (https://github.com/PyCQA/isort/blob/5.6.4/isort/place.py#L63-L95) :

```
if (
    _is_module(module_path)
    or _is_package(module_path)
    or _src_path_is_module(src_path, root_module_name)
):
    return (sections.FIRSTPARTY, f"Found in one of the configured src_paths: {src_path}.")
```